# Selenium cannot find valid xpath for the button click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I'm learning selenium and I've met one problem. I was doing all things using xpath for buttons but with this one this doesn't work and I don't know why.

This is how looks button which I want to click (I want to click Order tickets button )

```
<div id="bookingOption" class="row top5" style="display: block;">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input name="bookButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Order tickets">
                </div>
            </div>
```

My java code for clicking this button

I am using xPath `//*[@id="bookingOption"]/div/input`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[ before @id='bookingOption']/div/input")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ before @id='bookingOption']/div/input")).click();
```

Here is website on which on I am practising it may be helpful. http://ticketmonster-jdf.rhcloud.com/

I will be very thankful for every help.

Comment: How does it fail now? What error? Also, watch the extra whitespace at the beginning of the xpath expression.

Comment: in the second line of your code there is a missing `[` before `@id=`; plus it won't compile because of wrong double quotes, please paste actual code

Comment: This doesnt give any errors. Just my selenium code is clicking everything then it comes to this button and nothing happen. It doesnt click it and no errors are given.

Comment: I changed it to  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ before @id='bookingOption']/div/input")).click(); and still this doesnt click this button

Comment: I understand you may be new to xpath, but please at the least make an effort to understand the syntax: the correct path is `//*[@id='bookingOption']/div/input`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
   `//input[@value='Order tickets']`

Answer (score 0):

Remove **before** from **xpath("//*[ before @id='bookingOption']/div/input")**
the correct form for defining the xpath is

```
xpath("//*[@id='bookingOption']/div/input")
```